# How to obtain the posterior distribution of a given problem?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, posterior

> **Problem**:
>
> Compute the conditional distribution of a random variable $X$ given $Y$.
>
> - If a random variable $X$ is Bernoulli distributed with probability $q$ for $X = 0$.
> - The conditional distributions $p\left(y|X=0\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(2,1\right)$ and $p\left(y|X=1\right) =
>    \chi^2\left(3\right)$.

---

**ATTEMPT**:

The conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is
\begin{align} 
p(x|y) =  \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)} = \frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{p(y)} .
\end{align}

So, we need to compute
\begin{align} 
p(y) =  \underbrace{p(y|X=0)}_{= \mathcal{N}\left(2,1\right)} \underbrace{p(X=0)}_{q} + \underbrace{p(y|X=1)}_{=\chi^2\left(3\right)}  \underbrace{p(X=1)}_{= 1-q} 
\end{align}

Then, we can obtain the conditional distribution of $X = 0$ and $X = 1$ given $Y$ as
\begin{align} 
p(X=0|y) = \frac{ \underbrace{p(y|X=0)p(X=0)}_{q \ \mathcal{N}\left(2,1\right) }}{p(y)} ,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align} 
p(X=1|y) = \frac{ \underbrace{p(y|X=1)p(X=1)}_{ \left( 1-q\right) \ \chi^2\left(3 \right) }}{p(y)} .
\end{align}

Am I doing correctly? Thank you

---

Comment: You should not cross-post, so please delete either of the questions.

Comment: Posterior distribution is always conditional, so there is no "posterior of Y". You correctly calculated p(y). p(y|X) is given, so maybe the question asks about p(X|y)?

Comment: I have removed the post in maths.stackexchange now.

Comment: I tend to believe that probably the teacher meant to compute $p(x|y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)} =  \frac{p(y|x) p(x)}{p(y)}$. If it was then do I need to compute the numerator for either $X = 0$ or $X=1$?

Comment: I can't talk for your teacher.

Comment: @Tim: I understand. So, I have made an attempt to computer $p(x|y)$. Is this correct?